# Homology of $Z(x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2)\subset \mathbb{C}P^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, homology-cohomology, riemann-surfaces

I want to compute the homology of $M=Z(x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2)\subset \mathbb{C}P^2$. I think I have the answer, but I'm not sure how to make it precise.

My approach is to consider the affine cover $U_0=Z(x_0)^c$. Then under the homeomorphism $\varphi_0:[x_0:x_1:x_2]\mapsto (\frac{x_1}{x_0},\frac{x_2}{x_0})$ we find
$$\varphi_0(M)=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2\mid 1+x_1^2+x_2^2=0\}$$
Which we recognize as a Riemann surface. Now we know that we can compactify this Riemann surface by adding $2$ points at infinity, and the result will have genus 0. I suspect that these are exactly the points in
$$M\setminus U_0=\{[0:x_1:ix_2],[0:x_1:-ix_2]\}$$
And so we find that $M$ is homeomorphic to a sphere, which tells us its homology.

My problem is that I do not see how to incorporate these 2 missing points into the picture in a more precise\rigorous way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not directly prove it is isomorphic to the projective line? For example, changing variables to $(x_0+ix_1, x_0-ix_1,ix_2)$, this curve $M$ is same as the one given by $x_0x_1-x_2^2=0$ and you have a map $\mathbb{P}^1\to M$, by $(u,v)\mapsto (u^2, v^2, uv)$, which you can easily see to be an isomorphism.

Comment: thank you for your answer. How would you generalise this more variables, e.g. $x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$?

Comment: Quadrics are very well studied and its homologies are not difficult to calculate (often done using induction and long exact sequences). If $X$ is a quadric as yours in an even dimensional projective space, then $H^2k(X,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ for $0\leq k\leq\dim X$. If it is in an odd dimensional projective space, everything is same except in the middle you get two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of one.

Comment: could you point me to a reference?

Comment: I learned it from Hodge and Pedoe, but am sure many other modern text books have them.

Comment: Sorry to get back to you about this so late, but I cannot find this information in the book you mentioned by Pedoe and Hodge. Can you suggest what I can google to find the information I need?

Comment: Try googling integer cohomology of hyperquadrics.